# How to organise importing mixins, filters and directives in a large VUE project

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-directives, vue-mixin, vue-filter

) I am coding a really big vue app and now I have a question, how to organise importing mixins, filters and directives. I am in trouble because I see that I don't understant how to do it((( I hope somebody coud help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to organise...

it depends...

- are you working with a team or alone?
- Do you want to move fast or keep your app maintainable?
- Does your app have a user base (critical) or is it a side project?

The first question I would ask is what code is duplicated and can be simplified or generalized.

The goal is to shrink the code as much as possible while staying clean. Remember that in six months you will want to read your changes and immediately know what is going on.

If you are using Vue 2, I would ask the question, why are you using filters?
It is one of the [breaking changes](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/introduction.html#breaking-changes) when it comes to migrating to Vue 3. Think of another solution, like methods or computed properties (easily implemented).

This question cannot be answered here. It is too opinion based. There are many cases to consider and everyone has their own preference. Some like code splitting, some like to collect a lot in one file. Some a mixture, depending on how important or often functions are used.

Sorry.